# how to use CHQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding in this code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

```
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://titusandbindu.com/bm/wc-api/v2/customers"]];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"GET";
    static NSString *key=@"ck_3045dfb6122e50a79b1a35268078c4bc";
    static NSString *secret=@"cs_a7ac11bc25431b1234377d4c30aed8ce";
    static NSString *HMAC_SHA1=@"HmacSHA1";
    NSString *timestamp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
    NSString *nonce=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)arc4random()  * 100000000];
    NSLog(@"key:%@,secret:%@,timestamp:%@",key,secret,timestamp);
    NSLog(@"%@",nonce);


NSMutableDictionary *jsonpassdict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[jsonpassdict setValue:key forKey:@"oauth_consumer_key"];
[jsonpassdict setValue:HMAC_SHA1 forKey:@"oauth_signature_method"];
[jsonpassdict setValue:timestamp forKey:@"oauth_timestamp"];
[jsonpassdict setValue:nonce forKey:@"oauth_nonce"];
```

**Error is:**

```
 NSString *parametersString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",CHQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding(jsonpassdict , NSUTF8StringEncoding)];
NSLog(@"%@",parametersString);
//NSString *parametersString = CHQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding(jsonpassdict, NSUTF8StringEncoding);
```

Comment: Please post the error you are seeing, not just the code that causes it.

Comment: 1.... Implicit declaration of function 'CHQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding' is invalid in C99                             2.....Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC

Answer (score 5):

```
OAuth Authentication in iOS
===========================
# OAuth Authentication in iOS
responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
NSString *httpMethod = @"POST";
NSString *baseURL = @"";      // Server Url
NSString *oauthConsumerKey = @"ck_3045dfb6122e50a79b1a35268078c4bc";
NSString *oauthConsumerSecret = @"cs_a7ac11bc25431b1234377d4c30aed8ce";
NSString *oauth_timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", [[NSDate    date]timeIntervalSince1970]];
NSString *oauthNonce = [self generateRandomStringOfLength:42];
NSString *oauthSignatureMethod = @"HMAC-SHA1";

static NSString *username=@"";   // User Name
static NSString *password=@"";   // Password

 NSMutableString *parameterString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithFormat:@""];


[parameterString appendFormat:@"&oauth_consumer_key=%@", [oauthConsumerKey stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[parameterString appendFormat:@"&oauth_nonce=%@", [oauthNonce stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[parameterString appendFormat:@"&oauth_signature_method=%@", [oauthSignatureMethod stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[parameterString appendFormat:@"&oauth_timestamp=%@", [oauth_timestamp stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", username, password];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",[authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed]];
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

NSString *signatureBaseString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&%@&%@", httpMethod, [baseURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], [parameterString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *signingKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&", [oauthConsumerSecret stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *oauthSignature = [self hmacsha1:signatureBaseString secret:signingKey];


NSMutableString *authHeader=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@?oauth_consumer_key=%@&oauth_signature_method=%@&oauth_timestamp=%@&oauth_nonce=%s&oauth_signature=%@",[baseURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[oauthConsumerKey stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[oauthSignatureMethod stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[oauth_timestamp stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[oauthNonce UTF8String],[oauthSignature stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"%@",authHeader);

NSString *email=self.mailTextFiled.text;
NSString *Username=self.nameTextField.text;
NSString *Password=self.passwordTextField.text;



NSDictionary *customer=@{@"customer" : @{@"email": email,
                                         @"password" : Password,
                                         @"first_name": @"",
                                         @"last_name": @"",
                                         @"username": Username,
                                         @"billing_address": @{  },
                                         @"shipping_address": @{  }
                                         }
                         };
NSMutableDictionary *customers=[customer mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"%@",customers);

NSError *jsonSerializationError = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:customers options:kNilOptions error:&jsonSerializationError];

if(!jsonSerializationError) {
    NSString *serJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Serialized JSON: %@", serJSON);
} else {
    NSLog(@"JSON Encoding Failed: %@", [jsonSerializationError localizedDescription]);
}
request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:authHeader]] ;
//[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"]; // 2
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; // 3
[request setHTTPBody: jsonData];


[request setHTTPMethod:httpMethod];

[request setValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

[connection start];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you `#import`ing the header file for `CHQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding`?
2. `CHQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding` returns an `NSString`.

In your `stringWithFormat` you are using a `%d`. You should use `%@` since it's returning an `NSString`.

```
NSString *parametersString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",CHQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding(jsonpassdict , NSUTF8StringEncoding)];
```

Comment: How to import CHQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding ..?

Comment: Are you working with this project? https://github.com/Christian-Hansen/simple-oauth1

Comment: If you are modifying that project, did changing the `stringWithFormat:` method fix your problem? If you are cutting and pasting code, you need to have a better understanding of how the code you're using is structured.

Comment: Now I'm able to connect with sever use Oauth without using CHQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding